# Hexadecimal 7 segment display behaviour?

Tags: assembly, memory, hex, cpu

Using Assembly Language for PEPE-16 (16-bit Education Specialized Processor)

When addressing three 4-bit hexadecimal displays, it results in a weird behaviour:

```
DISPLAYS EQU 0A000H

PLACE 0 

MOV R1, 3
MOV R2, DISPLAYS

cicle:
    MOVB [R2], R1
    JMP cicle
```

The displays are supposed to show:

```
003
```

But instead, everytime I run the code, the first digit is completely random:

```
A03
403
103
703
C03
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an instruction set reference for PEP-16?  It's not a commonly known architecture.

Comment: At a guess, movb writes a byte, which represents two digits.  To set the third digit you need to write to another address, maybe the byte above or below the one you are doing now.

Comment: My gut feeling was using the MOV instruction because it's a 16 bits total on the displays. Turns out I was right all along and what was actually happening was some bad wiring on the circuit. The logic on my circuit wasn't correct therefore I had those weird display behaviours.